# Predicates of guava has gone obselete in SwaggerConfig file after springfox updated to 3.0.0, How to resolve?

Tags: swagger, guava, predicate, swagger-2.0, springfox

This is my SwaggerConfig file. Predicates used from "com.google.common.base.Predicates" has gone obselete after updation of springfox to 3.0.0

```
@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration
public class SwaggerAutoConfig {

    @Value("${project.name}")
    String projectName;

    @Value("${project.description}")
    String projectDescription;

    @Value("${project.version}")
    String projectVersion;

    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(Docket.class)
    @Bean
    public Docket swaggerSetup() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/error.*")))
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .tags(new Tag("Endpoint for faking the /islive and /isready /health
                                      info","Endpoint for faking the /islive and /isready /health
                                      info."));
    }
```

Apparently I tried using Predicate from java.util.function which seems to be working fine. Is there any other way to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Cause : Transitive Dependency between guava and springfox

Before moving on to Swagger 3.0.0, guava (com.google.guava) was a transitive dependency in springfox (io.springfox.swagger2) which used to contain the Predicates method

[image: dependency tree for swagger 2.9.2]

In new release, guava has been dropped from springfox.

[image: dependency tree for swagger 3.0.0]

Solution :

Addition of guava dependency can be done separately in your pom.xml file

[image]